# FFMpeg mxf streamcopy strips vbi_vanc_smpte_436m stream

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi i was using ffmpeg to copy all video/audio/data streams across to another mxf file and noticed that ancillary data streams weren't being copied and in fact caused an error.

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Media\61003203.mxf" -map 0 -c copy "D:\Media\POC_61003203.mxf"
```

I wasn't looking for the stream to be decoded/encoded but just a stream copy.
Any ideas?

```
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[mxf @ 00000000020f24a0] material track 68: has 3 components
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.5 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.6 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.7 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.8 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.9 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.10 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.11 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.12 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.13 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.14 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.15 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.16 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.17 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.18 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.19 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.20 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.21 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.22 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.23 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.24 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.25 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.26 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.27 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.28 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.29 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.30 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.31 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.32 : mono
Input #0, mxf, from 'D:\Media\test\61003203.mxf':
  Metadata:
    company_name    : Grass Valley
    product_name    : K2
    product_version : 9.6.4.2374
    product_uid     : caf3d2ff-9425-4086-addf-66f77967f101
    modification_date: 2016-11-02T10:39:56.000000Z
    generation_uid  : 14bd7cca-9235-148c-036a-28fe20524153
    uid             : 14bd7d74-9235-148c-1b22-28fe20524153
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD7D929235148C04D
028FE20524153
    material_package_name: Material Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/610032
03
    timecode        : 17:03:58:15
  Duration: 00:38:59.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 90620 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [S
AR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Video Track #1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #1
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #2
    Stream #0:3: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #3
    Stream #0:4: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #4
    Stream #0:5: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #5
    Stream #0:6: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #6
    Stream #0:7: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #7
    Stream #0:8: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #8
    Stream #0:9: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #9
    Stream #0:10: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #10
    Stream #0:11: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #11
    Stream #0:12: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #12
    Stream #0:13: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #13
    Stream #0:14: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #14
    Stream #0:15: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #15
    Stream #0:16: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #16
    Stream #0:17: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #17
    Stream #0:18: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #18
    Stream #0:19: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #19
    Stream #0:20: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #20
    Stream #0:21: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #21
    Stream #0:22: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #22
    Stream #0:23: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #23
    Stream #0:24: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #24
    Stream #0:25: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #25
    Stream #0:26: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #26
    Stream #0:27: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #27
    Stream #0:28: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #28
    Stream #0:29: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #29
    Stream #0:30: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #30
    Stream #0:31: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #31
    Stream #0:32: Audio: pcm_s24le, 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Audio Track #32
    Stream #0:33: Data: none
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010F431300000014BD8A269235148C7F772
8FE20524153
      file_package_name: Source Package for EUSNBKS005/V:/B02-Playout/61003203
      track_name      : Material Package: Data Track #1
      data_type       : vbi_vanc_smpte_436M
[mxf @ 000000000290c460] track 33: could not find essence container ul, codec no
t currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operat
ion not permitted
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
  Stream #0:5 -> #0:5 (copy)
  Stream #0:6 -> #0:6 (copy)
  Stream #0:7 -> #0:7 (copy)
  Stream #0:8 -> #0:8 (copy)
  Stream #0:9 -> #0:9 (copy)
  Stream #0:10 -> #0:10 (copy)
  Stream #0:11 -> #0:11 (copy)
  Stream #0:12 -> #0:12 (copy)
  Stream #0:13 -> #0:13 (copy)
  Stream #0:14 -> #0:14 (copy)
  Stream #0:15 -> #0:15 (copy)
  Stream #0:16 -> #0:16 (copy)
  Stream #0:17 -> #0:17 (copy)
  Stream #0:18 -> #0:18 (copy)
  Stream #0:19 -> #0:19 (copy)
  Stream #0:20 -> #0:20 (copy)
  Stream #0:21 -> #0:21 (copy)
  Stream #0:22 -> #0:22 (copy)
  Stream #0:23 -> #0:23 (copy)
  Stream #0:24 -> #0:24 (copy)
  Stream #0:25 -> #0:25 (copy)
  Stream #0:26 -> #0:26 (copy)
  Stream #0:27 -> #0:27 (copy)
  Stream #0:28 -> #0:28 (copy)
  Stream #0:29 -> #0:29 (copy)
  Stream #0:30 -> #0:30 (copy)
  Stream #0:31 -> #0:31 (copy)
  Stream #0:32 -> #0:32 (copy)
  Stream #0:33 -> #0:33 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Comment: Not supported [yet](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/726). Try [libMXF](http://ingex.sourceforge.net/libMXF/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, and the links. I'm not asking ffmpeg to decode/encode the stream just to copy it as is to another mxf. Surely it can do this in a stream content agnostic kind of way.

Comment: There's container header & packet metadata which is dependent on the nature of the stream content. That code hasn't been added.